# $\cos 3+\cos 7+...+\cos(2 n+3)= $to a compact formula

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to get a formula that has a fixed number of terms for this ecuation:

$$\cos 3+\cos 7+...+\cos(2n+3)=?$$

For example: a product of trigonometric functions

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: Whats the formula then?

Comment: $\cos 3+\cos 7+...+\cos(2n+3)=?$ is false.

Comment: As it stands, your equation is impossible to interpret. Do you mean $\cos 3 + \cos 5+\dcots$? Or do you mean $\cos(4n+3)$?

Comment: One could joke that the formula is unbounded thus cannot be compact :D

Answer (score 0):

Try [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry). Miracles can happen. You will encounter a geometric series. But it only works for summation.

Comment: A direct reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Other_sums_of_trigonometric_functions

Comment: You can use mathematical induction to prove them.

Answer (score 0):

$$S= \cos 3+\cos 7+...+\cos(2n+3) \\
2\sin(2)  S= 2\sin 2\left(\cos 3+\cos 7+...+\cos(2n+3) \right) \\
=2\sin2 \cos3 +2\sin2 \cos 7 + ... +2\sin2 \cos (2n+3)$$

Now, using the identity 
$$2\sin x \cos y = \sin(y+x)-\sin(y-x)$$ we get
$$2\sin(2)  S=(\sin 5-\sin1) + (\sin9-\sin 5) + ... +(\sin(2n+5)-\sin(2n+1) \\
2\sin(2)  S=\sin(2n+5)-\sin(1) $$

Answer (score -1):

$${\frac {\cos \left( 5+2\,n \right) -\cos \left( 3+2\,n \right) -\cos
 \left( 3 \right) +\cos \left( 1 \right) }{2\,\cos \left( 2
 \right)-2 }}
$$

Comment: Just taking a formula out of your sleeve is not that useful for the OP. Deriving the formula would be useful.

Comment: It can be obtained using Euler's formula and a geometric progression, as apprenant noted.